# Error de compilación Execution failed for task en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Estoy tratando de implementar una librería que me permite realizar una impresión en una impresora térmica bluetooth, el problema es que me esta surgiendo un error al momento de realizar la compilación en mi dispositivo o emulador, simplemente no se como poder solucionar, alguien podría ayudarme en esto

```
Error::

    FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/3.0.1/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android-3.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Estos son mis archivos de configuracion del gradle
build.gradle(app)

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testappprint"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1'
 }
```

build.gradle(setting gradle)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Pareciera que el classpath `debugRuntimeClasspath` no tiene incluidas ubicaciones "locales" o "privadas" para buscar las dependencias que deben cargarse, pues está buscando `ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1` en repos públicos en los que seguro seguro no has publicado tu app aún.

Comment: Y como podría solucionar esto? como hago esa búsqueda en repos públicos y privados?

Answer (score 1):

En el README del proyecto que intentas usar (y que debiste leer :P ), explican en el paso 1 que necesitas añadir en el `/build.gradle` **raíz** el repositorio:

```
repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
```

Ese es un servicio que expone artefactos de proyectos en GitHub, para que puedan halarse como dependencias gradle o maven.

Y DESPUÉS es que añades la dependencia en `app/build.gradle` no es el mismo archivo):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.0.1'
}
```

Revísalo; con esto debería encontrar esa dependencia

Comment: Si claro, de esa forma lo estoy realizando, que es lo normal, pero aun asi me sigue generando ese error, editare mi pregunta para agregar esos dos gradle como lo tengo configurado